# ffmpeg dropping packets from rtp stream without warning message

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, packet-loss

I am using a custom python script to create and send RTP packets to ffmpeg, which then converts it into s16le audio frames that are read from stdout. For this I use
`ffmpeg -i rtp://0.0.0.0:9000 -f s16le -ar 8000 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -loglevel debug -`
on the receiving side.

The audio received sounds fine, but the number of packets reported varies. 
I get that there might be packet loss with UDP (though every 2nd-5th run for a 50 second file while streaming on the same machine seems high), but

- there are no warning or error messages
- when I intentionally skip (drop) a packet in the python script, I get a message
- when I had not yet worked out the packet timing, I got messages
- when I switch the sequence number for two packets (so that `seq=1001` is sent before `seq=1000`), I get a message
- tcpdump shows all packets and in the correct order
- the machine has 48 cores and was relatively idle

My question is: Why do I have packet loss while there are no errors/warnings/messages and no issues visible in the network dump?

Comment: (Disclaimer: a pure speculation) If Redundant Audio Data in RTP a real thing (there are google hits but don't know if it's actually being implemented), can it explain the behavior? (either it was able to recover the lost packets or there are extra packets)

Comment: very interesting idea, but I'm constructing the RTP packets in python and I didn't (at least intentionally) add redundant audio data. Also I believe the change in received packets always corresponded to equivalent change in created audio bytes (2x as alaw encoding is 1 byte per frame and linear is 2)